# What does this rowspan piece of code mean?

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I have written some code which prints out a table and to merge the column together I was given this piece of code and was wondering if anyone could comment what it actually means/does?

```
td rowspan="{count(key('detailsByLocality',normalize-space(LocalityName))) + 1}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't see how the key is defined nor the source XML, nor do we know the current context - so the only possible answer is a very general one:

It counts the "related" nodes - i.e. the nodes that match the *match pattern* defined in the `detailsByLocality` key, whose *use expression* is equal to the value of the current node's child named `LocalityName`.